# How to get substring from URL?

Tags: java

I have couple of URL's like
http://toidsu.abc.tnd:9083/login/pages/selection.xhtml#
http://toifsmdu.abc.tnd:9081/login/pages/selection.xhtml#

I want to get string up to 'http://toidsu.abc.tnd:9083' and 'http://toifsmdu.abc.tnd:9081'
How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this class to parse it for you: [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)